# How to access the final simplex tableau in CPLEX?

Tags: java, cplex, simplex

I'm solving a LP with CPLEX using the Java API. I build my model with the methods provided (like `cplex.numVar(col, lb, ub)` and `cplex.addLe()`)  After optimization is done, I'm interested in reading the simplex tableau of the final iteration (to be precise: not only the duals and reduced costs but also the coefficients inside the tableau).

I tried to access the IloLPMatrix object `cplex.LPMatrix()`, but this only returns an empty matrix. I'm interested in the "filled" matrix associated to the problem I just solved.

So, how can I read the simplex tableau?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you *cannot* access the simplex tableau with the Concert (Java/.NET/C++) APIs. You can access this advanced feature with the C Callable Library and Python APIs, though. For example, see [CPXXbinvarow](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcallablelibrary/cpxapi/binvarow.html) and [examining the simplex tableau in the Python API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/APIs/Python/13_simplex_tableau_eg.html).

Now, to clear up your possible confusion with what `IloLPMatrix` does, consider the following (mostly cribbed from [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014457637) thread on the official IBM developerWorks forum).

If you add constraints to the model with `cplex.addLe()` then you can use [rangeIterator](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/ilog/cplex/IloCplexModeler.html#rangeIterator()) to access them (and possibly [conversionIterator](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/ilog/cplex/IloCplexModeler.html#conversionIterator()), [SOS1Iterator](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/ilog/cplex/IloCplexModeler.html#SOS1iterator()), [SO2Iterator](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/ilog/cplex/IloCplexModeler.html#SOS2iterator())). Note that when you use `rangeIterator` you have to figure out the runtime type of an expression before you can get at the coefficients. For example:

```
for (Iterator it = cplex.rangeIterator(); it.hasNext(); /* nothing */) {
   IloRange range = (IloRange)it.next();
   IloNumExpr expr = range.getExpr(); // Cannot get the coefficients of expr directly :-(
   if (expr instanceof IloLinearNumExpr) {
      IloLinearNumExpr linExpr = (IloLinearNumExpr)expr;
      for (IloLinearNumExprIterator jt = linExpr.linearIterator(); jt.hasNext(); /* nothing */) {
          IloNumVar var = jt.nextNumVar();
          double coef = jt.getValue();
          ...
       }
   }
   else if (expr instance of ...) {
      ...
   }
}
```

On the other hand, if you build your model with an [IloLPMatrix](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/ilog/concert/IloLPMatrix.html), then you can access it with [LPMatrixIterator](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/ilog/cplex/IloCplexModeler.html#LPMatrixIterator()). When you call [cplex.LPMatrix](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/ilog/cplex/IloCplexModeler.html#LPMatrix()) it "Creates and returns an empty LP matrix object." You then have to fill it and `add` it to the model. Alternately, you can use [addLPMatrix](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/ilog/cplex/IloCplexModeler.html#addLPMatrix()) to create and add it in one step (you still need to populate it).

For example:

```
// Create a matrix in which we setup the model.
IloLPMatrix matrix = cplex.LPMatrix();

// Create variables.
IloNumVar x = cplex.numVar();
IloNumVar y = cplex.numVar();
matrix.addCols(new IloNumVar[]{ x, y });

// Create constraint x + y <= 2.
IloLinearNumExpr lhs = cplex.linearNumExpr();
lhs.addTerm(x, 1.0);
lhs.addTerm(y, 1.0);
matrix.addRow(cplex.le(lhs, 2.0));

// When all constraints are setup add the matrix to the model.
cplex.add(matrix);
```

Note that you can only add linear constraints when using an `IloLPMatrix`.

Whether you use the first method to build your model and `rangeIterator` to access it, or the second method and `LPMatrixIterator`, is a matter of taste and possibly some performance trade-offs; you'd have to experiment with both approaches.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I (falsely) expected `clpex.getLPMatrix()` to return a matrix for the current model... 
Though, I still have some questions... Using your first code-snippet, can I access any other information than the _original_ coefficients? (This won't help, since I already know them)
Do you know, why it's not possible to access the simplex tableau? I would assume, this is a common use case...

Comment: The techniques in the code snippets are there to access the original coefficients. Indeed, it is not very useful unless you are reading in a model, etc., where you did not build it in the first place.

Comment: As the documentation for `CPXXbinvarow` indicates, it is considered an "advanced routine". If you search for "tableau" on the official [IBM developerWorks forum](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/forum?id=11111111-0000-0000-0000-000000002059) you'll see that it is not something that comes up very often. Surely, if there were greater demand for this functionality it would have been in the product long ago.

Answer (score 0):

In `CPLEX_Studio128\cplex\examples\src\java` you could have a look at the example `LPex1.java`.